# How to link the spacy named entities to the the text from a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, spacy, entities

I have a list of dictionaries containing text:

`list_dicts = [{'id': 1, 'text': 'hello my name is Carla'}, {'id': 2, 'text': 'hello my name is John' }]`

I applied Spacy named entity recognition on the nested texts like so:

```
for d in list_dicts: 
    for k,v in d.items():
        if k=='text':
            doc = nlp(v) 
            for ent in doc.ents:
                print([ent.text, ent.label_])
```

The output is a printout of the named entity text and its corresponding label, for example:

```
    ['Bob', 'PERSON']
    ['John', 'PERSON']
```

I would like to add the named entities to their corresponding text in each nested dictionary,which would look like this:

`list_dicts = [{'id': 1, 'text': 'hello our names are Carla and Bob', 'entities':[['Carla',   'PERSON'], ['Bob':'PERSON']]}, {'id': 2, 'text': 'hello my name is John', 'entities': [['John', 'PERSON']] }]`

As for now, I attempted to implement zip() as a method for linking the entities to the original text and later convert these to a new list of dictionaries, but it seems zip() does not work with the Spacy objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dict.setdefault`

**Ex:**

```
for d in list_dicts: 
    doc = nlp(d['text'])
    for ent in doc.ents:
        d.setdefault('entities', []).append([ent.text, ent.label_])
```